# Usuário recebe resposta que funciona depois apaga

Tags: debate

Um usuário que recebeu uma resposta correta minha, agradeceu depois apagou o post. Poderiam revisar o perfil? Desconfio que este usuário já tenha feito isso antes (acho que é o segundo que eu respondo depois é apagado, creio que o outro foi no sábado). Como proceder neste caso? Creio que não são exercícios de escola (universidade) mas parecem ser coisa do trabalho.
Ainda possuo em cache o post apagado. Tem como fazer uma auditoria?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][`link da mais recente apagada`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499448/transformar-o-output-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-uma-lista/499452#499452)

[image: deleteItem]

Comment: Olá Danizavtz. Nesse perfil do link que você citou não constam respostas suas. Será que você confundiu os links? Poderia checar novamente?

Comment: Olá, adicionei a evidência da resposta a esta pergunta, inclusive ela está com -2. Como posso pegar o link?

Comment: Não temos como ficar vendo prints, o link que você postou no corpo da pergunta não é o mesmo das prints.

Comment: Ajustei o link, obrigado

Comment: Usuários que apagam muitas postagens e que não conseguem gerar boas perguntas para o site geralmente são vetados automaticamente, provavelmente em breve vai ocorrer isso com a conta dela, pois já teve muitas postagens deletadas, mais detalhes em: [**Por que não posso mais fazer perguntas?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). De resto não temos mais o que fazer, o próprio sistema irá resolver o caso e o usuário só poderá voltar se melhorar e restaurar as postagens existentes.

Comment: Gui é essa aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/499452/137387

Comment: @AugustoVasques sim, ele já corrigiu o link na pergunta, inclusive por isso comentei acima que a autora tem muitas publicações deletadas, não só essa.

Comment: Ele apagou porque recebeu negativo provavelmente (o que acontece sem nenhuma razão muita vezes), além de ter sido fechada, pra ele não tinha razão deixar ela lá.

Comment: Tendo em vista que estamos em uma comunidade, as perguntas deveriam, teoricamente, ser feita não só para se beneficiar, mas também aos demais usuários do site. Talvez o que justifique esse tipo de comportamento seja o amplo número de helpdesks (que é o que o site se tornou de um tempo pra cá), pois o usuário tem sua dúvida sanada, e já não precisa mais da pergunta, podendo excluir ou não, principalmente porque na maioria dos casos de helpdesks, as perguntas são mal formatadas e recebem justos negativos.

Comment: Mas voltando ao foco principal da questão, é o que o @GuilhermeNascimento já disse. O sistema cuida desses casos, caso haja exageros ou abusos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quando a pergunta é boa e a resposta também, então é conteúdo que interessa para comunidade e pode sinalizar que a moderação pode recuperar a pergunta e consequentemente a resposta.

Nesse caso específico, a pergunta deveria ser fechada, então removê-la não é algo ruim; por isso não vale a pena recuperar. A pergunta é só um *helpdesk* específico para a pessoa, ou seja, é um pedido de "faz pra mim" e, por isso sequer deveria ter sido respondida, portanto não será recuperada.

Como bem disse o Guilherme, usuários que postam esse tipo de pergunta costumam fazer sempre assim e rapidamente perdem o direito de postar novas perguntas, especialmente quando apagam a postagem.

Só é possível manter qualidade de conteúdo quando as pessoas só postam boas perguntas e respostas em perguntas que podem contribuir para a comunidade em vez de contribuir só para o indivíduo, conforme já amplamente discutido aqui no meta.